# Auto quote arguments in zsh

Tags: command-line, zsh

It's a long shot, but I was wondering if there was a way in `zsh`, with certain commands, to automatically quote the rest of the line.  Eg, for the command `he`

```
he (foo*bar + baz)^2
```

I want it to parse as if I had written

```
he '(foo*bar + baz)^2'
```

The reason is that I like to call out to Perl or Haskell for certain tasks and I don't like having to worry about quoting (esp. because sometimes I have reason to use single quote in the expression).

Answer (score 6):

I think `rc_quotes` option is good enough.

```
RC_QUOTES
       Allow the character sequence  `'''  to  signify  a  single  quote
        within singly quoted strings.  Note this does not apply in quoted
        strings using the format $'...', where a backslashed single quote
        can be used.
```

But if you want, you can write a custom accept-line widget to auto quote for you.

Here is an example, it will quote everything behind `python -c`:

```bsh
function quote-accept-line() {
    local -a starts_with=("python -c ")
    for str ($starts_with) {
        if [[ ${(M)BUFFER#$str} ]] {
            BUFFER=$str${(qq)BUFFER#$str}
        }
    }
    zle accept-line
}
zle -N quote-accept-line
# bind it to "Enter"
bindkey "^M" quote-accept-line
```

Copy these code to your `~/.zshrc`.